# ConcurrentHashMap in JDK7 code explanation (scanAndLockForPut)

Tags: concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

The [source codes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.scanAndLockForPut%28java.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) of the method scanAndLockForPut in ConcurrentHashMap in JDK7 says:

```
private HashEntry<K,V> scanAndLockForPut(K key, int hash, V value) {
    HashEntry<K,V> first = entryForHash(this, hash);
    HashEntry<K,V> e = first;
    HashEntry<K,V> node = null;
    int retries = -1; // negative while locating node
    while (!tryLock()) {
        HashEntry<K,V> f; // to recheck first below
        if (retries < 0) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (node == null) // speculatively create node
                    node = new HashEntry<K,V>(hash, key, value, null);
                retries = 0;
            }
            else if (key.equals(e.key))
                retries = 0;
            else
                e = e.next;
        }
        else if (++retries > MAX_SCAN_RETRIES) {
            lock();
            break;
        }
        else if ((retries & 1) == 0 &&
                 (f = entryForHash(this, hash)) != first) {
            e = first = f; // re-traverse if entry changed
            retries = -1;
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

I understand what the codes mean, but what I don't is this else if entry:

```
else if ((retries & 1) == 0 && (f = entryForHash(this, hash)) != first)
```

My question is:
**Why do we have to do "(retries & 1) == 0"?**

***EDIT***:
I kind of figure it out. It's all because the constant MAX_SCAN_RETRIES:

```
static final int MAX_SCAN_RETRIES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() > 1 ? 64 : 1;
```

In single core processor, MAX_SCAN_RETRIES = 1. So the second time the thread steps into the loop "while(tryLock)", it doesn't have to check whether the first node was changed.

However, in multi cores processor, this will behave like checking whether the first node is changed every 2 times in the while loop.

Is the above explanation correct?

Comment: No, your explanation is not correct. Having a single CPU core does *not* mean there is no concurrency. Even single core machines can have preemptive multi-tasking. Making any assumption based on the number of cores is wrong. And, by the way, the result of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` is allowed to change over time. See [its JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors())

Comment: @Holger Yes! I realize that after I posted my edit, but I decided to left it unchanged. So if not the explanation, what then?

Comment: I can only guess and I don’t want to post speculations. In the end, the Java 8 implementation looks completely different and understanding this particular piece of code is not important to me…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked this question on the concurrency-interest mailing list, and the author(Doug Lea) himself replied:

> Yes. We need only ensure that staleness is eventually detected.
>   Alternating the head-checks works fine, and simplifies use of
>   the same code for both uni- and multi- processors.

[link](http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2014-August/012881.html)

So I think this is the end of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down:

1:

```
(retries & 1) == 0
```

This returns 1 for odd numbers, 0 for even numbers. Basically, to get past, there's a 1 in 2 chance, if the number is even.

2:

```
f = entryForHash(this, hash)
```

f is a temporary variable used to store the value of the latest entry in the segment.

3:

```
(/* ... */) != first
```

Checks if the value changed. If it did, it would move the current entry to the start, and re-iterate the linked nodes again in attempt to acquire the lock.

Comment: Yes, I understand the whole "else if" mean. What I don't is the particular "(retries & 1) == 0". Why do we have to determine whether retries & 1 equals to 0?

Comment: I believe it's used to make sure the last elements don't get left out, it's an educated guess though so take this with a grain of salt

Answer (score 0):

I think there  are some bugs for the method!
first let us see the put method:

```
final V put(K key, int hash, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
        HashEntry<K,V> node = tryLock() ? null :
            scanAndLockForPut(key, hash, value);//1. scanAndLockForPut only return
                                                //   null or a new Entry
        V oldValue;
        try {
            HashEntry<K,V>[] tab = table;
            int index = (tab.length - 1) & hash;
            HashEntry<K,V> first = entryAt(tab, index);
            for (HashEntry<K,V> e = first;;) {
                if (e != null) {
                    K k;
                    if ((k = e.key) == key ||
                        (e.hash == hash && key.equals(k))) {
                        oldValue = e.value;
                        if (!onlyIfAbsent) {
                            e.value = value;
                            ++modCount;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    e = e.next;
                }
                else {
                    // 2. here the node is null or a new Entry
                    //    and the node.next is the origin head node 
                    if (node != null)
                        node.setNext(first);
                    else
                        node = new HashEntry<K,V>(hash, key, value, first);
                    int c = count + 1;
                    if (c > threshold && tab.length < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
                        rehash(node);
                    else
                        setEntryAt(tab, index, node);//3. finally, the node become 
                                                     // the new head,so eventually 
                                                     // every thing we put will be 
                                                     // the head of the entry list
                                                     // and it may appears two equals
                                                     // entry in the same entry list.
                    ++modCount;
                    count = c;
                    oldValue = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            unlock();
        }
        return oldValue;
    }
```

step: 1. scanAndLockForPut only return  null or a new Entry.

step: 2. the node eventualy a new Entry, and the node.next is the origin head node

step: 3. finally, the node become the new head,so eventually  every thing we put will be the head of the entry list and it may appears two equals entry in the same entry list when the concurrentHashMap works in a concurrent environment.

That is my opinion, and I am not exactly sure about whether it is right or not. So I hope you all give me some advice,thanks a lot!!